# Закрытие одной View при открытии другой C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте! Предположим имеется два представления. View1 появляется при загрузке формы, а View2 по нажатию на кнопку. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при появлении View2 View1 исчезло? На данный момент у меня появляется View2, но View1 остаётся висеть и просвечиваться через View2
[image: Пример]

Представления биндятся следующим образом:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="v1" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View1ViewModel}">
        <views:View1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="v2" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View2ViewModel}">
        <views:View2 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

Во View1 идёт привязка

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding View2}"/>
```

По нажатию кнопки срабатывает команда

```
private RelayCommand showView2;

    public RelayCommand ShowView2
    {
        get
        {
            return showView2 ??
                (showView2= new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    View2Form = new View2ViewModel();
                }));
        }
    }
```

Свойство View2, которое будет отображаться

```
private object view2Form;

    public object View2Form
    {
        get { return view2Form; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(view2Form, value))
                return;
            view2Form= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("View2Form");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Во View1 идёт привязка

<ContentControl Content="{Binding **View2Form**}"/>

Comment: какой-то запутанный код

Comment: не уверен, что понимаю что вы хотите реализовать? что-то вроде навигации?

Comment: [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Answer (score 2):

Ну вы почти сделали всё правильно, смена View через `ContentControl` — хороший, правильный путь. Просто вы не протянули команду во View1, и поэтому включаете View2 не там, где надо: на уровне View2, а не на уровне корневой VM.

Вот наброски того, как должно быть.

Для начала, VM для первого и второго View.

```
class View1ViewModel
{
    public View1ViewModel(ICommand showView2) { ShowView2 = showView2; }
    public ICommand ShowView2 { get; }
}

class View2ViewModel
{
}
```

`View1ViewModel` должна выставлять команду перехода во второй View.

Теперь, главная VM. Я написал стандартную реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged` (она у вас, по идее, должна быть в родительском классе). А также переименовал `View2Form` в `SubViewModel`. Команду смены VM я передаю `View1ViewModel` в конструкторе (сама `View1ViewModel` эту команду создать не может, т. к. эта команда должна менять свойства главной VM!).

```
class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainVM()
    {
        ShowView2 = new RelayCommand(obj => SubViewModel = new View2ViewModel());
        SubViewModel = new View1ViewModel(ShowView2);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private object subViewModel;
    public object SubViewModel
    {
        get { return subViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(subViewModel, value))
                return;
            subViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public ICommand ShowView2 { get; }
}
```

`View1` выглядит просто:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ShowView2}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="Show View 2"/>
```

И `View2`:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Text="I am View 2"/>
```

Главное окно практически без изменений (только привязка к `SubViewModel`):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View1ViewModel}">
        <views:View1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View2ViewModel}">
        <views:View2 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SubViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Всё получилось! А подскажите, что если я захочу, чтобы на кнопку "Show View 2" выполнялась команда, которая прописана во View1ViewModel. Просто некоторые свойства изменяются, которые работают только для View1, не хотелось бы всё в MainVM переносить

Comment: Т.е я жму на "показать второе представление", сначала выполняется моя команда основная, и в случае успеха открывается второе представление, а в случае неудачи меняются некоторые свойства для первого представления, прописанные во View1ViewModel и привязанные к View1

Comment: @БыстровДмитрий: Тогда вы должны всё равно передать команду перехода (обозначим её №1) из MainVM, а в View1ViewModel определить свою команду №2, которая будет выполнять то, что нужно, а потом дёргать команду №1 (то есть, вызывать `Execute` у неё). И тогда к кнопке нужно привязывать команду №2.

Comment: Могли бы вы привести пример, как это сделать?

Comment: @БыстровДмитрий: А что именно вам непонятно? Как определить новую команду? Как привязать к ней кнопку?